# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-routing

My app module router module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{path: 'home' , component: HomeComponent},
{path:'edit/:id', component:EditComponent},
{path: 'messages' , component: MessageComponent},
{path: '', redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
])
```

My second module:

```
RouterModule.forChild
([
{
path:'first',
component:FirstComponent,
outlet:'admin'
},
{
path:"second",
component:SecondComponent
},
{
path:"admin",
component:AdminComponent,
outlet:'admin'
}
])
```

My app.component.html:

```
<div >
  <router-outlet>
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-1">
           <router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet>
      </div>
  </router-outlet>
</div>
```

So whenever I use router inside my .ts file like this one,everything works fine,

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: { admin: ['admin']}}]);
```

but when i try to use it inside my html with routerLink like this one:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: { admin: ['admin']}}]">routr</a>
```

I am getting error "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'".
I am using newest version of angular cli, and I have `<base href="/">` inside my `<head>` tag. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add HomeComponent to your RouterModule.forChild as following

```
RouterModule.forChild
([
{
path:'',
redirectTo: '/home',
pathMatch: 'full'
}
])
```

Also in your module.ts change to this:

@NgModule({
imports:
RouterModule.forRoot(forChild)

Where forChild is an export const

Comment: Then you have to delete it from your module.ts

Comment: Tanks for your quick response, but same thing happens, everything works fine using router inside my .ts file, and reporting error if I try to use it using routerLink inside html.

Comment: Are you sure to import "Routes" from @angular/router? Maybe you could add ErrorHandler function to  provides a custom error handler as in the docs then post your error : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html

Comment: @Vahid Please vote for my answear if it was helpfull